# Access JSON data in JAVA like JavaScript

Tags: java, json

I hope I am not asking a question which don't make any sense. Lets say I have JSON data like below. In JAVA we can access data by using **get** method (ex. `jsonObj.get("field1")`). When it comes to JavaScript we can access data directly using field name (ex. `jsonObj.field1`). So my question is, is there anyway in JAVA (or any 3rd party class) which allow me to access JSON data directly using field name?

```
   { 
      "field1" : "value1",
      "field2" : "value2"
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636163/how-to-get-a-value-from-gson-object-by-key

Comment: [Other useful links](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+parse+json)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  can you explain me how is it a duplicate question? did you at least read what I asked? I know how to parse JSON response. Next time please read the question before you blindly mark it as duplicate.

Comment: You're right. Duplicate vote removed.

Comment: @abdurrahimefe, can you point me where can I see the answer to my question in the link you provided?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON library and create object model class, then individual properties can be access using getter's

```
    File file = new File("XXXXXX.json");
    String JSONString = Files.toString(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    ModelClass modelClass = gson.fromJson(JSONString, modelClass.class);
    System.out.print("modelClass field -->" + modelClass.getFIELDNAME());
```

Hope this helps!

Note: field name and type used in model class should be same as field name and type from JSON.

Comment: Thanks @NayanSuchak. I am aware of that but, I want to access it like a static variable ex. `obj.FIELDNAME` not by any methods.